# Undefined offset: 0 in laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

first of all, I convert an array to a collection to be able using collection methods, and then do some processes on this collection...
but there is an offset error!
Could You tell me where is my mistake ?

```
public function MassTransferCh2Q1()
{


    $a1 = range('1', '40', '0.3');
    $a2 = range('4', '44', '0.3');
    $a3 = range('1', '40', '0.5');
    $a4 = range('5', '45', '0.5');

    $calculated = [];

    //calculate  #36 Answers array
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 35; $i++){

        $calculated[$i] = ($a1[$i]/($a1[$i]+$a2[$i]))*(-1*$a3[$i]) + ($a2[$i]/($a1[$i]+$a2[$i]))*($a4[$i]) ;
        $calculated[$i] = $this->truncate_number($calculated[$i]);

    }

    //Convert $calculated Array to a Collection
     $results = collect($calculated);


    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($results); $i++){

        //select Correct answer
        $correctAnswer = $results->only($i);

        //delete correct answer from calculated collection, so $calculate collection will be equal to incorrect answers ...
        $incorrectAnswers = $results->except($i);

        //select 5 random item from incorrect answers collection
        $randIncorrectAnswers = $incorrectAnswers->random(5);


        $answerModel = New Answer();


        $answerModel->correct_ans = $correctAnswer;
        $answerModel->question_id = '1';

        for($n = 0; $n <= 5; $n++){
            $answerModel['incorrect_ans_'.$i] = $randIncorrectAnswers[$n];
        }

        $answerModel->save();


    }
    return $results;



}
```

Comment: which line has error ?

Comment: Use `$results->count()` instead of `count($results)`, also change `<=` to `<`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test your code, but it looks to me that this line is wrong:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($results); $i++)
```

and should be:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)
```

You start with index 0, if result holds 36 items, you are trying to access $result[36] and that one doesn't exist.